# Как настраивать размер скриншотов на GitHub?

Tags: изображения, скриншоты

Залил на GitHube скриншоты моего приложения, когда всё сохранил, они получились размером с пол экрана монитора, как уменьшить их размер?

Comment: Да любым редактором.

Comment: @Эникейщик, то есть это делается до загрузки на GitHub?

Comment: `![](screenshot =1000x1000)`?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда вставлять эту строку, у меня есть стро, отвечающая за отображение скриншота: ![alt text](screenshots/Screenshot_20200201-195527.jpg "Скриншот приложения")
нужно вставлять куда-то в неё или в другое место (у меня пока не получилось)

Comment: Изменить размер изображения можно используя стандартный `html` таг `img`, например, ```<img src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/screenshot.jpg" width="400" height="790">``` Что до чистого `markdown` там все не так очевидно, поэтому лучше шибко с ним не заморачиваться.

Comment: @greg zakharov, огромное Вам спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По состоянию на начало 2020 года это можно сделать только тегом HTML:

```html
<img src="path/to/screenshot.png" width="500">
```

Все старые приёмы [не работают](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2554#issuecomment-158936360).

Comment: Премного благодарен!